# how to use static user in borrow item from item list with sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My problem is tied with sqlite and android studio.

I'm trying to use a static user to add to a foreign key table and itemlist.

to tie the user with the item that he borrowed.

I'm confused about how to use the button borrow in a sql foreign key database.

I sadly couldn't find something that includes the same problem I've had

the databasehelper problem file

```
public boolean addBorrow(int ID,String Item, String MARK ) {
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query =  "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ORDER +
    COL2 + " SELECT FROM " + TABLE_ITEM +
       " WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + ID +  "'";

    String query1 =  "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ORDER +
            COL2 + " SELECT FROM " + TABLE_USER +
            " WHERE " + COL7 + " = '" + MARK +  "'";

    db.execSQL(query);
    db.execSQL(query1);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_ORDER, null, contentValues);

    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


public static final String ITEM_DB = "items.db";
public static final String TABLE_ITEM = "items_data";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "ITEM";
public static final String COL3 = "ITEMCATEGORIE";
public static final String COL4 = "ITEMDESCRIPTION";
public static final String COL5 = "ITEMQUANTITY";


public static final String USER_DB = "user.db";
public static final String TABLE_USER = "user_data";
public static final String COL6 = "ID_USER";
public static final String COL7 = "MARK";


public static final String ORDER_DB = "order.db";
public static final String TABLE_ORDER = "order_data";
public static final String COL8 = "ID_ORDER";
```

the addBorrowItem file

```
@Override
protected  void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstancesState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_item_layout);
    vBorrow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vBorrow);
    Borrow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Borrow);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    vBorrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(addBorrowedItem.this,ViewBorrowedItem.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Borrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!BorrowItem.equals("")){
                myDB.addBorrow(BorrowItem,selectedID,ItemName,Username);

            }else {
                toastMessage("you must enter a name");
            }
        }
    });
```

vBorrow = viewborrow button in xml

Borrow = borrow button in xml

I hoped that the item would add itself into its the list of borrowed items

instead, I get the error

> Non-static method 'equals(java.lang.Object)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Is this because I tried to add a static object with a non-static one?

Comment: *i hoped that the item would add itself into its the list of borrowed items* is a really remarkable sentence in context of programming... `BorrowItem.equals("")` is a static call of the method `equals()`, which is non-static. You have to instantiate a `BorrowItem` in order to use this method and you have to compare it to another instance of `BorrowItem`, not to a `String` (`""`).

Answer (score 0):

> i hoped that the item would add itself into its the list of borrowed
>   items

Defining a foreign key, using something like  `column references parenttable(parentcolumn)` adds a rule (a constraint) that a value assigned to column has to be a value in the parentcolumn of a row in the parenttable.

It does not insert values into tables. You have to determine the value.

If you have a parent table (food) with values bread, butter, milk in a column food and a table menu with `chosenfood references food(food)` then

```
insert into menu (menuname,chosenfood) values('Menu1','bread')
```

would insert a row into the menu table.

```
insert into menu (menuname,chosenfood) values('Menu2','eggs')
```

would not insert a row as there is no eggs row in the food column of the food table.

Your thought would imply that SQLite on you behalf should decide that using

```
insert into menu (menuname) values('Menu3')
```

would pick the appropriate value from the list bread, butter and milk. Which would it pick? (that is rhetorical). It cannot know weather the right value is bread, butter or milk.